# Такой ли медленный with

Tags: javascript

Собственно очень давно читал о том что работает медленно, на практике так и не использовал но вот начал читать очередную книгу по javascript и вспомнил...
Интересует действительно ли следует отказаться от этой конструкции несмотря на все ее удобства?

Comment: Согласно ECMAScript-5, в Strict режиме, использование with - запрещено.

Comment: Я в курсе. Там очень много чего запрещено и юзаю я его раз в 100лет

В ECMAScript-5 я возверую тогда когда он будет поддерживаться > 80% браузеров, а пока, это всего-лишь рекомендации. Да и Strict режим это тоже, по сути, всего-лишь рекомендация

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть бенчмарк конструкции `with` в `js` - [http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/demos/jswithspeed_test.html](http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/demos/js_with_speed_test.html)

```
function withTest() {
  var temp = '';
  with(document.forms[0]) {
    for(var i=0;i<100000;i++) {
      temp = '';
      temp = id;
      temp = '';
      temp = action;
      temp = '';
      temp = innerHTML;
    }
  }
}
function alternativeMethodTest() {
  var temp = '';
  var f = document.forms[0];

  for(var i=0;i<100000;i++) {
    temp = '';
    temp = f.id;
    temp = '';
    temp = f.action;
    temp = '';
    temp = f.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

В моем случае разница была совершенно незначительной.

- В случае, если конструкция `with` *применялась вне цикла*, то **результаты составили `3725ms` против `3312ms`.**
- В случае, если конструкция `with` была *внутри цикла на каждой итерации*, то **результаты - `3915ms` против `3313ms`.**

Т.е, если порассуждать, то применять, конечно стоит, но в случае, если например, какой-либо фрагмент кода хочет соптимизовать, то от `with` можно отказаться для улучшения производительности.

**P.S**

`Chrome 14.0.835.163`

*Допускаю, что в других браузерах результат может быть другим, хотя и не верю, что он будет катастрофически отличаться.*

Comment: спасибо за тест, самому нереально лениво было его делать...<br>
Действительно разница незначительная...